# Convert time to readable format

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have time like this in the database

```
                [open_time] => 10:00:00
                [close_time] => 23:00:00
```

I want to convert it into readable form like 10:00am 11:00pm

I tried this:

```
$open = date("g:s a",$time['open_time']);

$close = date("g:sa",$time['close_time']);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`date`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) expects an integer argument, the traditional [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Try this:

```
date('g:s a', strtotime($time['open_time']));
```

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) attempts to convert a string into an integer Unix timestamp as expected by `date`.

Answer (score 2):

If it's in your database, consider using the [MySQL DATE_FORMAT() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) directly in your request

Answer (score 2):

The second argument needs a UNIX timestamp (epoch time):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

> timestamp
>
> The optional timestamp
>   parameter is an integer Unix timestamp
>   that defaults to the current local
>   time if a timestamp is not given. In
>   other words, it defaults to the value
>   of time().

```
<?php
$t = time();
print_r($t);
print_r(date('g:i a', $t));
?>
```

gives

```
1288935001
10:30 pm
```